# Asymptotics relationship from algebraic identity?

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function

### Background

We start with the identity:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r \ln r  + \ln (r-1)! = n\ln n! $$

$$ \implies \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n} \ln r  + \frac{1}{n} \ln\Gamma(r) = \ln n!$$

$$ \implies \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n} \ln (\frac{r}{n}) + \frac{r}{n} \ln(n)  + \frac{1}{n} \ln\Gamma(r) = \ln n! $$

$$ \implies \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n} \ln (\frac{r}{n}) +  \frac{1}{n} \ln\Gamma(r) =  -\frac{(n+1)}{2} \ln(n) + \ln n!  $$

$$ \implies \sum_{r=1}^n (\frac{r}{n} \ln (\frac{r}{n}) +  \frac{1}{n} \ln\Gamma(r))\frac{1}{n} =  -\frac{(n+1)}{2n} \ln(n) + \frac{\ln n!}{n}  $$

$$ \implies \sum_{r=1}^n (\frac{r}{n} \ln (\frac{r}{n})) \frac{1}{n}  =  -\frac{(n+1)}{2n} \ln(n) -\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2} \ln\Gamma(r) + \frac{\ln n!}{n}  $$

Defining $ F(n) = \int x \ln (x) dx = \frac{n^2}{2}\ln(n) - \frac{n^2}{4} $

$$ \implies \frac{1}{F(n)}\sum_{r=1}^n (\frac{r}{n} \ln (\frac{r}{n})) \frac{1}{n}  = \frac{1}{F(n)}(-\frac{(n+1)}{2n} \ln(n) + \frac{\ln n!}{n}  -\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2} \ln\Gamma(r))) $$

Taking $\lim n \to \infty$ and defining $G(n)$ as the BarnesG function:

$$ \implies \frac{n^2}{2}\ln(n) - \frac{n^2}{4} \sim  \frac{-1}{2} \ln(n) -\frac{1}{n^2} \ln G(n+2) + \frac{\ln n!}{n}    $$

$$ \implies - n \ln n! + \frac{n^4}{2}\ln(n) - \frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{n^2}{2} \ln(n) \sim   -  \ln G(n+2)  $$

$$ \implies   n \ln n! - \frac{n^4}{2}\ln(n) + \frac{n^4}{4} - \frac{n^2}{2} \ln(n) \sim     \ln G(n+2) $$

### Question(Edited)

I found my mistake .... Is this algebric identity known? Also, is weather this relation between the factorial function and the BarnesG function is known?

Comment: It appears that your starting point, $\sum_{r=1}^n r \ln r  + \ln (r-1)! = n \ln n$, is not true.

Comment: @antonio Vargas can u give an explicit example?

Comment: Well for $n=3$ we have $$\sum_{r=1}^{3} r\ln r + \ln(r-1)! = \underbrace{0 + 0}_{r=1} + \underbrace{2\ln 2 + 0}_{r=2} + \underbrace{3\ln 3 + \ln 2}_{r=3} = 3\ln 2 + 3\ln 3 \neq 3\ln 3$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas You were right and I corrected my question ....